# NPM Package not publishing

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried publishing my npm package with:

```sh
npm publish --access=public
```

on both github actions and my computer, but get the same error:

```sh
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@quantalabs%2fepijs - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@quantalabs/epijs@1.2.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

despite `v1.0.0` and `v1.1.0` already being published on npm.

Why is this happening?

UPDATE - View the complete log [here](https://github.com/Quantalabs/EpiJS/runs/2798171597?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: https://status.npmjs.org/ - The status page looks fine, but the same error came up [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8465) and the server was down. Perhaps there's a relation?

Comment: It seems that the npm token I was using was deleted!

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that you are logged in